# How do I subset a 2-dimensional array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been looking around, and seen that it is possible to retrieve an element from a two dimensional array with something like `myArray[x][y]`. However what I am looking to do take everything but the first column.

In R one would just use `myArray[x,2:y]` however I am aware that the colon is a completely different operator in Javascript.

Thanks

Comment: you can always just offset from the first column, why won't that work?

Comment: @epoch How would you go about offseting from the first column? Assuning you had an array of the form `myArray = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to take everything in `y` try `map`:

```
var y = myArray.map(function(v){ return v[1] });
```

Not sure if this is the equivalent of the R you posted...

If you want to subtract the first column try like:

```
return v.slice(1);
```

Comment: From what I understand that returns an array of the first elements of each of the original arrays.

Comment: Mmm, I'm not sure I understand your question but if you have `a = [[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]` it will return `[2,2,2]`.

Comment: Ah yes, you're correct, I'm used to 1-indexed languages. However that still does not solve my problem, say I had `myArray = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` and wanted to retrieve `[[2,3],[5,6],[8,9]]`

Comment: Then you can return those columns: `return [v[1],v[2]]`

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll just have to do that, I was hoping there would be a cleaner method as I am working with a slightly larger array.

Comment: If you just want to get rid of the first element you can do this dynamically, check my edit.

Comment: The slice function seems to work outside the `map` function, however once inside I get the error that `slice` is undefined.

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake, that works perfectly. Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

Your example where you had myArray = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] and wanted to retrieve [[2,3],[5,6],[8,9]]

you could do something like this:

```
var myArray = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];    
var results = [];

for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
  results.push(myArray[i].slice(1,3));
}
//results === [[2,3],[5,6],[8,9]];
```

If you want to slice the indexes after index[0] from each sub-array, then you might want to go with this approach instead:

```
var myArray = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];    

var sliceSubset = function(array){
  var results = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    results.push(array[i].slice(1,array[i].length));
  }
  return results;
}

sliceSubset(myArray); //returns [[2,3],[5,6],[8,9]]
//works on different sized arrays as well
var myOtherArray = [[1,2,3,9],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
sliceSubset(myOtherArray); //returns [[2,3,9],[5,6],[8,9]]
```